# No message body reader for readentity for bytearray

Tags: rest, cxf, cxf-client

No message body reader for readentity for bytearray

This occurs while read byte response from cxf client.

```
Response r = client.get();
byte[] barray = r.readEntity(byte[].class);
```

cxf version is 2.7.6

Please suggest how I can add message body reader in this.

Your suggestions are valuable ..

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the incoming bytes using `InputStream`

```
Response r = client.get();
InputStream in = (InputStream)r.getEntity();
byte[] barray = IOUtils.readBytesFromStream(in);
```